# Can someone tell me why this code is not running?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I am working on beamforming. For the same, there is an example code on MathWorks website on acoustic beamforming. When I am trying to run the code it shows the error "Undefined variable `phased` or class `phased.OmnidirectionalMicrophoneElement`."
Can someone tell me how to resolve this?

Here is the code

```
microphone = phased.OmnidirectionalMicrophoneElement('FrequencyRange',[20 20e3]);

Nele = 10; ula = phased.ULA(Nele,0.05,'Element',microphone); c = 340;  % sound speed, in m/s\

ang_dft = [-30; 0]; ang_cleanspeech = [-10; 10]; ang_laughter = [20; 0];

fs = 8000; collector = phased.WidebandCollector('Sensor',ula,'PropagationSpeed',c,...
    'SampleRate',fs,'NumSubbands',1000,'ModulatedInput', false);

t_duration = 3;  % 3 seconds t = 0:1/fs:t_duration-1/fs; prevS = rng(2008); noisePwr = 1e-4; % noise power % preallocate NSampPerFrame
= 1000; NTSample = t_duration*fs; sigArray = zeros(NTSample,Nele); voice_dft = zeros(NTSample,1); voice_cleanspeech = zeros(NTSample,1); voice_laugh = zeros(NTSample,1);

% set up audio device writer audioWriter = audioDeviceWriter('SampleRate',fs, ...
        'SupportVariableSizeInput', true); isAudioSupported = (length(getAudioDevices(audioWriter))>1);

dftFileReader = dsp.AudioFileReader('dft_voice_8kHz.wav',...
    'SamplesPerFrame',NSampPerFrame); speechFileReader = dsp.AudioFileReader('cleanspeech_voice_8kHz.wav',...
    'SamplesPerFrame',NSampPerFrame); laughterFileReader = dsp.AudioFileReader('laughter_8kHz.wav',...
    'SamplesPerFrame',NSampPerFrame);

% simulate for m = 1:NSampPerFrame:NTSample
    sig_idx = m:m+NSampPerFrame-1;
    x1 = dftFileReader();
    x2 = speechFileReader();
    x3 = 2*laughterFileReader();
    temp = collector([x1 x2 x3],...
        [ang_dft ang_cleanspeech ang_laughter]) + ...
        sqrt(noisePwr)*randn(NSampPerFrame,Nele);
    if isAudioSupported
        play(audioWriter,0.5*temp(:,3));
    end
    sigArray(sig_idx,:) = temp;
    voice_dft(sig_idx) = x1;
    voice_cleanspeech(sig_idx) = x2;
    voice_laugh(sig_idx) = x3; end

plot(t,sigArray(:,3)); xlabel('Time (sec)'); ylabel ('Amplitude (V)'); title('Signal Received at Channel 3'); ylim([-3 3]);
```

Comment: I am removing the `processing` tag since the question has nothing to do with the programming language known as [Processing](https://processing.org/). Please read the description of a tag before deciding to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to purchase Phased Array System Toolbox from Matlab for this to run.